# Combinations for filling data in C++

Tags: c++

Can someone help me with the way how can we think of the algo for the following case :

I have `n` spaces , now each space can be filled with `m` different items ( This `m` can be different for each space).

I want to get all possible combinations of the `n` spaces filled with each of `m` different items ( basically totally number of combinations we will have : `m0Cn0` x `m1Cn1` x.....  ( Where C is the "Combination" in Permutations & Combinations theory)

*Example:*

Given 3 gaps to be filled: First gap (`g0`) can choose numbers (`0 or 1`), second gap (`g1`) can choose numbers from (`0 to 6`), similarly third gap (`g2`) chooses from (`0 to 6`)

How do I get all the possible combinations?

For instance, a combination for `g2` `g1` `g0` could be `550`

Comment: Could you edit your question and add a small example?

Comment: Hey @FabioTurati I have added the example. Can you please check once

Comment: If I understood that correctly, you can just have 3 nested for loops that each loops through the correspoinding range: g0={0,1}, g1={0,10,20,...,60} ect. Just add the numbers inside the loop and push it into a vector.

Comment: Are you looking for [Cartesian_product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) ?

Comment: @dani : The number "3" which I mentioned in example can be dynamic. So it could be 6 or 7.....any number based on runtime input

Answer (score 0):

You can do a simple recursive method that tries all the possibilities:

```
void f(int pos, const vector<int>& choices, vector<int>* solution) {
  if (pos > choices.size()) {
    HandleNewSolution(*solution);
    return;
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < choices[pos]; ++i) {
    solution->at(pos) = i;
    f(i + 1);
  }
}
```

To call it set the number of options for each position in a vector, create a vector to hold the solution and call with position 0.

```
vector<int> options = {2,3,4,2};
vector<int> solution(4);
f(0, options, &solution);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you please help explain if possible in further detail. couldnt understand the usage of  " solution->at(pos) " and what is solution(4) meaning

Comment: `at` accesses one element of the vector (as `[]` but with out-of-index check). See [reference](http://it.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at). The `solution(4)` part is just the declaration (a `vector` of `int` of size 4). See [reference](http://it.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector)

Comment: @user3304726 Just like dirluca said. In this case you can replace `at` with `(*solution)[pos]` and `solution(4)` with `vector<int> solution = {0,0,0,0};`